# How to trap a PHP script error which dies (Perl has eval)?

Tags: php, error-handling

I've got a script which works fine on our development server but dies on the clients server.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if (function_exists('simplexml_load_file')) echo "function exists";
if (file_exists('test.xml'))
{
echo("<hr>just about to read local xml file :".__LINE__); 
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');   // dies here
```

In Perl you can trap such errors with eval, is there anything equivalent in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the manner in which the function fails.

In the case of `simplexml_load_file()`, the error info is [well documented](http://us.php.net/simplexml_load_file#function.simplexml-load-file.returnvalues)

> On errors, it will return FALSE.

and

> Produces an E_WARNING error message
>   for each error found in the XML data.

and

> Tip
>
> Use `libxml_use_internal_errors()` to
>   suppress all XML errors, and
>   `libxml_get_errors()` to iterate over
>   them afterwards.

And, you can always [set your own error handler](http://us.php.net/set_error_handler) or use the (troublesome) [error suppression operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

Comment: Peter
It never returns from simplexml_load_file, tried your suggestions to no avail

Comment: yep, their sysadmin is on the job but also having problems

Comment: I guess just get what info you can from their error logs.  What error_reporting level are you using on their server?

Answer (score 0):

Sysadmin:-
I've briefly turned on verbose error reporting and it's come back with this:

Fatal error: Cannot clone object of class SimpleXMLElement due to
'zend.ze1_compatibility_mode' in

http://archives.devshed.com/forums/php-108/simplexml-problem-982459.html

This configuration can be overridden on a per site basis with a
.htaccess file directive
http://www.activecollab.com/forums/topic/616/

> this solved the problem. But why couldn't I turn on this level of error reporting from within my script?